# Adding conditional formatting to a value less than 0

Tags: excel

I have a column which has time values which will either be a positive or a negative figure. I want the negative time values to be in red. The format of these cells is 'Custom' and then '[h]:mm:ss'. I have added the negative '-' prefix using the `CONCAT` function:

```
=IF(H3="Yes",CONCAT("-",F3),F3)
```

When selecting 'if less than 0' in the conditional formatting, the negative cells aren't being highlighted. I am guessing this is because I have simply prefixed the time values with a '-' prefix rather than it actually being a negative time. I am unsure how to enable the conditional formatting to work?

Here is a sample of the data:

[image]

Columns are E, F, and G from left to right

Comment: If you select any of these cells, and press `CTRL+1` then what format the cell is showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Home → Conditional Formatting → Highlight Cell Rules → Text that contains (type "-")
2. Select the cells in which you want to highlight the negative numbers in red.
3. In the dialog box, specify the value below which the formatting should be applied. If you want to use formatting other than the ones in the drop-down, use the Custom Format option.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Sorry I think you miss understood the question. I'm aware of how you conditionally format but the issue I have is that the conditional formatting is not working as I have prefixed the time value with a "-"

Comment: then let me revised the answer (please see the revised one)

Comment: Thanks for you response. When using the formula =IF(H3="Yes", (F3 * -1),F3), I get the error 'A value used in the formula is of the wrong data type'

Comment: I have tried setting the format of the cells to both general and number, neither have resolved the issue

Comment: let me futher revised the answer (revised - point 1 in my answer, please try)

Comment: Thank you this worked! I did know this...sorry